# Flutter android splash shifts upward in devices with larger height

Tags: android, splash-screen

Here is the **`launch_background.xml`** code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/splash_color" />
    <item
        android:width="160dp"
        android:height="58dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/hal_logo"
        android:gravity="center" />

</layer-list>
```

The screen moves a bit upward while showing in screens with large heights. I tried with the **`bitmap`** as well. The same issue exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed all the generated code with `viewTreeObserver` and `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` check from `MainActivity.kt` and kept only the line after `super` method:

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
    }
}
```

Now it's working as expected, no more shifting upwards.

Answer (score 0):

I do it with a bitmap tag with no problems on bigger screens.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/colored_logo" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Maybe you might have a problem with the size of the logo, mine is 800x400 px

Comment: Did u try it with bitmap?

Comment: Yes. The same issue exists